# How can I track Lead Source "PPC - Google" in Salesforce

Tags: form, google, wordpress, adwords

How can I track the PPC efforts and know when someone makes an inquiry through the website whether they came through PPC. I want to know who those people are
Gravity Forms are integrated with SF. I’m looking for a solution where it automatically pulls through the lead source as PPC for Google Adwords.
When it comes to Lead Source here, I mean the information of who the people are.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to track the source of your leads, or just hard code the source as "PPC - Google" from a particular landing page?

If the latter, just add a hidden field to GravityForms that corresponds to the Salesforce Lead Source field, with that value.

If you wanted to track sources with keywords, referrers, etc. via Gravity Forms into Salesforce, check out [CloudAmp's Campaign Tracker](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009w2tgEAA) app. It is a paid plugin for Salesforce but does have a trial so you can see if it does what you want.

Best,
David